# How to capture single quote when using Perl in CLi?

Tags: perl, command-line-interface

Suppose I have a text file with content like below:

```
'Jack', is a boy
'Jenny', is a girl
...
...
...
```

I'd like to use perl in Cli to only capture the names between pairs of single quotes

```
cat text| perl -ne 'print $1."\n" if/\'(\w+?)\'/'
```

Above command was what I ran but it didn't work. It seems like "'" messed up with Shell.

I know we have other options like writing a perl script. But given my circumstances, I'd like to find a way to fulfill this in Shell command line.

Please advise.

Comment: not related to the question, but you can drop the `cat` and use `perl -ne '...' text` instead.

Answer (score 3):

The shell has the interesting property of concatenating quoted strings. Or rather, `'...'` or `"..."` should not be considered strings, but modifiers for available escapes. The `'...'`-surrounded parts of a command have *no* escapes available. Outside of `'...'`, a single quote can be passed as `\'`. Together with the concatenating property, we can embed a single quote like

```
$ perl -E'say "'\''";'
'
```

into the `-e` code. The first `'` exits the no-escape zone, `\'` is our single quote, and `'` re-enters the escapeless zone. What `perl` saw was

```
perl        // argv[0]
-Esay "'";  // argv[1]
```

This would make your command

```
cat text| perl -ne 'print $1."\n" if/'\''(\w+?)'\''/'
```

(quotes don't need escaping in regexes), or

```
cat text| perl -ne "print \$1.qq(\n) if/'(\w+?)'/"
```

(using double quotes to surround the command, but using `qq//` for double quoted strings and escaping the `$` sigil to avoid shell variable interpolation).

Answer (score 0):

Here are some methods that do not require manually escaping the perl statement:

(Disclaimer: I'm not sure how robust these are – they haven't been tested extensively)

1. Cat-in-the-bag technique

   ```
   perl -ne "$(cat)" text
   ```

   You will be prompted for input. To terminate `cat`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>.

   One shortcoming of this: The perl statement is not reusable. This is addressed by the variation:

   ```
   $pline=$(cat)
   perl -ne "$pline" text
   ```
2. The bash builtin, `read`

   Multiple lines:

   ```
   read -rd'^[' pline
   ```

   Single line:

   ```
   read -r pline
   ```

   Reads user input into the variable `pline`.

   The meaning of the switches:

   - `-r`: stop `read` from interpreting backslashes (e.g. by default `read` interprets `\w` as `w`)
   - `-d`: determines what character ends the `read` command.

     - `^[` is the character corresponding to <kbd>Esc</kbd>, you insert `^[` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd>.
3. Heredoc and script.
   (You said no scripts, but this is quick and dirty, so might as well...)

   ```
   cat << 'EOF' > scriptonite
   print $1 . "\n" if /'(\w+)'/
   EOF
   ```

   then you simply

   ```
   perl -n scriptonite text
   ```